# onSubmit throws "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me preface with this is my first time working on a React app from scratch coming from Vue, so I don't have much contextual knowledge and this may be stupidly simple.

I have a single input form with a button with an `onSubmit` directive to my function `onFormSubmit()`, but when I submit the form I'm seeing a TypeError `TypeError: this.props.onFormSubmit is not a function`.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class BrandInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      form: {
        brand: ''
      }
    }
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onFormSubmit(this.state.form)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let form = this.state.form
    form.brand = event.target.value
    this.setState({
      form: form
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form className="flex flex-row w-full" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <input type="text" className="w-full px-4 py-2 border rounded" placeholder="Check a brand" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></input>
        <button type="submit" className="px-4 ml-2 text-green-800 bg-green-400 rounded-lg">Search</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

I've looked at a bunch of examples for similar components as well as others experiencing the same issue and do not see the declaration done any differently than what I'm doing.

As well my `handleChange()` function is being called without issue, so is this something specific to how forms are to be submitted maybe?

Comment: This is because your `props` dont have a function that you are calling, check if the props have the function you are trying to call

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right! This confused me earlier so I renamed it and I was thinking the `onFormSubmit()` being referred to in this TypeError was the one on the form element. Thanks, guess that's an indication to brew some coffee!

Answer (score 0):

For sake of closing this question. As Akhil Aravind pointed out in the comment, this was due to the prop `onFormSubmit` not being defined, as I had gotten confused earlier with 2 definitions of `onFormSubmit` so I had renamed. Changed the name of the prop back to `onFormSubmit` to rectify the issue.

In my App.js

```
...
  onFormSubmit(form) {
    Request
    .post(this.state.api_url)
    .send({ form: form })
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .then((res, err) => {
      console.log(res)
        if(err) {
          this.setState({
            error: true
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            captured: true,
          })
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-3/4 mx-auto my-12">
        <Header />
        <BrandInput onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)}></BrandInput>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the parent component that you're passing the this.onFormSubmit props. You're likely facing this problem because you forgot to pass it as a prop.

Answer (score -1):

You should use that component like something this `<BrandInput onFormSubmit={() => true} />`, because you are using value from `props`.